# Javascript parsing various section, paragraph, figure, title etc. text from string and replace with bookmarks

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse out specific keyword patterns for section, paragraph, figure, table, appendix etc that are in the text in non-xml tagged strings. The pattern used will be applicable to any of these
once it works.  If I have multiple sentence paragraph text i.e. sentence 1. sentence 2, I'm having problems not picking up on the period of the sentence.  See the following test string I'm using.

.Section 1.11.3, test section   1.2. See section later(?). 1.1 section 1 .

This string is trying to account for alot of variations: spaces and tabs, commas, no section keyword paired with number and a section  with # followed by a period and a space before the period. I'm using https://ww.regexr.com to test my regexpr pattern.  It highlights the correct matches,
but it picks up on the period at the end of the sentence following the Section #, but if a space is
before the period (see the end of the test string above) it doesn't. Thus I'd like to extract,
"Section 1.11.3", "section    1.2" and "section 1" as strings. However, I'll get "section   1.2." instead with the sentences period at the end. Also any
"section" without a number it should skip over.

My pattern is,  /[Ss]ection(\s+[0-9]+(([.]){0,1}[0-9]*)*)/gm

How to eliminate the period after 1.2 as being part of the match?

Once selected keyword extracted, they will be replaced with Word bookmark and
hyperlink content.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the regular expression sequence to use for my test string above.
The ordering had to be reversed to first find the longest string to match
and if no match, then via the  (|) the shortest string is matched. One would think the ordering wouldn't matter but it does.

To find all "selection" combinations the pattern is,
[Ss]ection\s+((([0-9]+([.]{0,1}[0-9]+)*)+)|([0-9]+[^.]*))

To find all "selection" combinations with a number only the pattern is,

[Ss]ection\s+((([0-9]+([.]{0,1}[0-9]+)*)*)|([0-9]+[^.]*))

Comment: [Ss]ection\s+((([0-9]+([\.]{0,1}[0-9]+)\*)+)|([0-9]+[^.]\*))   this is the correct pattern for the first pattern above and for the second pattern. [Ss]ection\s+((([0-9]+([\.]{0,1}[0-9]+)\*)\*)|([0-9]+[^.]\*))     asterix's got dropped above and this comment had to escape them for posting.